# "Ich bin ein bisschen spät dran" Was heißt "dran"?

Tags: meaning, difference, meaning-in-context

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen

> Ich bin ein bisschen spät

und

> Ich bin ein bisschen spät dran?

Wenn ich einfach die erste Version benutze, klingt es als würde etwas fehlen?

Answer (score 4):

> Ich bin ein bisschen spät.

Kann man sagen, der Zuhörer denkt dann aber, es sei Perfekt und wartet noch auf ein Partizip. Zum Beispiel:

> Ich bin ein bisschen spät gekommen.
>
> Ich bin ein bisschen spät losgefahren.

Will man sich einfach nur in der Gegenwart entschuldigen, kann man aus *sein* das Vollverb *dran sein* machen, dann ist es klar, dass kein Partizip mehr folgt.

> Ich bin ein bisschen spät dran.

Comment: Das denkt ein Zuhörer nicht, wenn man es richtig betont. Wenn man statt "Ich bin spät dran." auf das "dran" verzichtet lässt man nicht nur das "dran" weg, sondern die Betonung ändert sich auch.

Comment: @userunknown: Das Argument finde ich schon für die mündliche Form nicht überzeugend, schriftlich wirkt der Satz unvollständig und wie eine zu wörtliche Übersetzung von *I'm late*.

Answer (score 2):

*Dran sein* bedeutet *an der Reihe sein*, etwa bei einem Gesellschaftsspiel oder beim Arzt.

Mehrere Personen werden der Reihe nach *dran geholt*. Die Person, die *an der Reihe* ist, ist jetzt *dran*.

Oder von mehreren Aufgaben, die sich einer Person in festgelegter Reihenfolge stellen, ist jetzt eine *dran/an der Reihe*.

Erst musste der Hefeteig gemacht werden, jetzt ist der Eischnee *dran/an der Reihe*.

Beim

> Ich bin ein bisschen spät dran.

ist man hinter dem Zeitplan zurück. Die Sache, um die es geht, hätte früher an der Reihe sein sollen; nicht weiter vorne in der Reihenfolge, aber am Zeitmaßstab gemessen.

Answer (score 1):

Das "dran" steht hier für quasi *"dran an dem, was ich eigentlich schon etwas früher machen wollte, was ich hier aber jetzt nicht weiter beschreibe"*

Das verwendet man also häufig um zu erklären das man sich jetzt beeilen muss/möchte. *Ich muss jetzt wirklich los - ich bin schon spät dran*

*Ich bin ein bisschen spät* würde ich verwenden wenn mein gegenüber direkt betroffen ist, z. B. zu meiner Verabredung: *Entschuldigung, ich weiß ich bin ein bisschen spät.* oder zum Verkäufer: *Ich weiß, ich bin ein bisschen spät, ich brauche nur kurz ...*

Answer (score -1):

Das Wort lautet eigentlich *ran*. Es geht Liason mit dem benachbarten t ein

> Wann komm ich ran?

> Du bist<sup>d</sup>ran.

Im gegebenfall verhält es sich genauso, "spät dran", und das lässt vermutens liege eigentlich ein Partizip vor, so wie bereits eingewendet wurde. Dabei ist aber die Grammatik der Niederdeutschen von den hochdeutschen Partizipien zu unterscheiden. Nur zum Vergleich: auf Englisch heißt es auch "wie ar raning lät", "weil se train häs rän erly". Ehrlich ey.

Denkbar wäre wegen gewisser Umstände die Herausbildung eines Augment, das unter anderem in "ready" vorliegt (vgl. "perfekt", ikaliänisch *perfetto* "völlig, vollkommen, perfekt, best"), quasi eine abgeschliffene Höflichkeitsformel mit Vorbild im Altgriechischen.

Alternativ wäre *dran* aus "daran" abzuleiten, da es als Adverbialobjekt etwa aus

> *sich an etwas machen*

folgt, wobei *da* den Platz des Objektes einnimmt, *mach dich (d(a))ran*, vgl. *es geht voran*. Das macht in dem gegebenen Beispiel aber nicht so viel Sinn. Trotzdem gibt es natürlich Theoristen die ganze Theoriekonstrukte auf der Annahme *dar+an* aufbauen würden.

Auch hier trifft der Vergleich mit dem englischen noch zu: "I must run", "Ick mut wieter-ran" (Bemerke Liason). Natürlich würde die Etymologie unterschiedliche Bedeutungen suggerieren, *ran (an die Arbeit)* sei Ellipse, während der Brite schreiend davon läuft.